# Java returns javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake. And PHP cURL - error No 35

Tags: java, php, curl

I try to connect to https://www.old.health.gov.il/units/achot/AchotSearch.asp?ahType=&p=1 using Java application but it returns "**javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake**". I have searched this error on the internet and it was said to add `System.setProperty("https.protocols", "TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2");`
However it didnt help. Then I decided to use PHP cURL function to connect to this page and it returned error No 35 (I tryed PHP 5.3 and 7.1 - same results).
After I have set `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION,2);` error has changed to 4. I am stuck! I cant understand what I do wrong! Please help!

Any help appriciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Solved! I have set `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION,4);` and it started to work!

Answer (score 0):

For java, you can try configuring `-Djavax.net.debug=all` and see what is the handshake error (assuming its a proof-of-concept there is only one thread in the jvm).

You could also try '`openssl s_client -connect host:port -showcerts`' (linux) and see what results you get.

If you are posting any ssl-debug information, be sure to mask out any pre-master-secret (cipher-key) that the debug log will inadvertently contain.